# Editing a bot's message based on a reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've just started with javascript trying to set up an discord bot with discord.js. I want to use this bot as an 'easy' way to organize 'Civ 6' groups. So people only need to click on the '+' reaction for the name to be added to a list

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

then the prefix and token etc etc...

```
client.on('message', message=>{    
    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
```

...stuff for checking the command

and then the actual command

```
switch(args[0]){
        case 'civ':
            const civ = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Civ 6 Group')
            .addField('Players Joined', message.author.username, true)
            .setColor(0x00FFFF)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
            .setFooter('Bot created by Plasy#0274')
            message.channel.send(civ).then(sentEmbed => {
                sentEmbed.react('718418753137803367');                             
                sentEmbed.react('718421670276235344');
            if (Discord.user.sentEmbed.react('718418753137803367'))then (message.channel.send('yes'))

            })
        break;
```

What can I do to make this work as I want it to? I am extremely stuck, so I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting inside this part :

```
message.channel.send(civ).then(sentEmbed => {
                sentEmbed.react('718418753137803367');                             
                sentEmbed.react('718421670276235344');
```

You'll need to create a reactionsCollector on the message.

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector), you can make one this way :

```
// Create a reaction collector
const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.id === '718418753137803367' || reaction.emoji.id === '718421670276235344') && user.id !== client.user.id;

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
collector.on('collect', (r, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${r.emoji.name}`);
    if (r.emoji.id === '718418753137803367') {
        // Do something with reaction 1
    }
    else if (r.emoji.id === '718421670276235344') {
        // Do something with reaction 2
    }
});
// This is optional.
collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
```

If I understood your question well, then you might also want to add the new names to your embed. Supposing you'll only have one field, you can achieve this by putting this code inside the "do something with..." parts :

```
sentEmbed.fields[0].value += `, ${user.username} *(Team 1 or 2)*`;
```

I hope this will put you on the right way, if you have any other questions, make sure to comment below

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215496/discussion-on-answer-by-tenclea-editing-a-bots-message-based-on-a-reaction).